# How to get a fall-through behavior in case statements in bash v3?

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

I just tested the following syntax on Linux:

```
case "$OSTYPE" in linux-gnu*) ;;& linux*) echo $OSTYPE; ;; esac
case "$OSTYPE" in linux-gnu*) ;& linux*) echo $OSTYPE; ;; esac
```

which works without any problems (See: [Can bash case statements cascade?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75354/can-bash-case-statements-cascade)) with `GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

But on OSX I've the following errors:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

It's `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`.

Any clues how to achieve the same fall-through behavior on bash v3?

Comment: Is your code in the first lines just a sample or the real code you want to run?

Comment: It's ready copy&paste code to run. The real script is [.bashrc](https://github.com/kenorb/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc) at lines 58-59 which are commented out, because they doesn't work on OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either upgrade your bash ([homebrew](http://brew.sh/)) or you'll have to recode it using a series of if statements:

```
case "$OSTYPE" in linux-gnu*) ;;& linux*) echo $OSTYPE; ;; esac
case "$OSTYPE" in linux-gnu*) ;& linux*) echo $OSTYPE; ;; esac
```

would be

```
# first case
if [[ $OSTYPE == linux-gnu* ]]; then
    : # nothing in this branch
fi 
if [[ $OSTYPE == linux* ]]; then
    echo $OSTYPE
fi

# second case
function print_ostype { echo $OSTYPE; }
if [[ $OSTYPE == linux-gnu* ]]; then
    # nothing in this branch
    # include the next branch
    print_ostype
elif [[ $OSTYPE == linux* ]]; then
    print_ostype
fi
```

I used a function in the 2nd case to reduce code duplication, in case there's multiple statements.

Comment: you should to use the `:` for the empty branch... the pure `# ...` throws error ;)